# Linq query help

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to convert this short SQL statement into linq but I am facing some difficulties, here's my latest attempt, apparently it has an error:

**SQL:**

```
select ProductID from products where
categoryID in (select categoryID from categories_sub 
               where categoryID='15' and category_sub_name = 'chiffon')
```

**Linq:**

'15' and 'chiffon' is replaced by parameter 'cID' and 'subCatID' here:

```
IQueryable<Categories_Sub > cat = (from c in db.Categories_Sub
                             where c.CategoryID == cID
                              & c.Category_Sub_ID == subCatID
                             select c);   


var subcat = (from c in db.Products
              where cat.Contains(c.ProductID)
              select c);
```

Comment: Linq to SQL or Entity Framework? What kind of error?

Comment: Huh? You look like you are selected all products where categoryID == 15 in your SQL query. Is this right? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What's the point of selecting `categoryID` when you later filter it by being equal `'15'`?

Comment: try this out: http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: My apology for the misinfo, the SQL statement was a sample.
'15' and 'chiffon' is replaced by parameter 'cID' and 'subCatID'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var Result = from p in products 
               from subc in categories_sub 
               where subc.categoryID=15 and 
                     subc.category_sub_name = "chiffon" and 
                     p.categoryID = subc.categoryID 
               select p.ProductID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimally, your code won't compile because there is an extra space before closing generic bracket.
The first line should start with `IQueryable<Categories_Sub>`.

Then, there is not enough information in your question. What LINQ provider are you using? What makes you think there is an error in query?

Answer (score 0):

I've reformatted the sql to talk about it in a little more depth

```
1 select ProductID
2 from products 
3 where categoryID in
4   (select categoryID 
5        from categories_sub 
6        where categoryID='15' and 
7              category_sub_name = 'chiffon')
```

Line 3 supposes you're looking for products with a specific categoryID

But your subquery starting on line 4, only returns a list of 0 or more categoryIDs that must = '15'

In which case, why not

```
1 select ProductID
2 from products 
3 where categoryID = '15'
```

I know this isn't an answer but it was too big to fit inside a comment.  I'll try to answer later.